# What is the right xmlns used for Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-comments

The Facebook documentation on this is inconsistent and confusing.

I. Here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

It says:

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

(if you fill in the form and click the get code button and then click the xfbml tag.)

II. On this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/opengraph-tutorial/#plugins

It says:

```
xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"
```

Now the two urls above resolve to the same url: http://graph.facebook.com/schema/og/

III. But then we have: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/

```
xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
      xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"
```

Now the first url here does not even resolve to a valid xml schema.

What is the proper xmlns:og to use to enable FBLike, Comment, and FB Connect?

I know that in the world of HTML 5 this is not important but for the case of older browsers, what should we do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use at the moment and works perfectly

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
      xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am doing right now. Both namespaces point to the same schema document.

```
<html xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```